# GET request in React.js to a server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get

I have a `SearchBar` and a `Profile` component and I want to make a GET request to the server: `http://awesomeserver/users`. The data in the server are in an array of objects. I want to be able to type in a username in the search bar and when I click "Search", I want to display that user's first name, last name, and email on the page. For example, when I search for jsmith, I want to display: First Name: John, Last Name: Smith, email: jsmith@gmail.com. In order to do that, I need to pass them as `props` to the `Profile` component. I am using axios to make the request, but I think I am not using it correctly. How do I search by username, but only retrieve the first name, last name, and email?

This is what a sample data would look like in the server:

```
{
  username: jsmith,
  firstName: John,
  lastName: Smith,
  email: jsmith@gmail.com,
  hobby: hiking,
  id: 1
}
```

This is my code so far:

```
//Profile Component

import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>First Name: {this.props.firstName}</div>
            <div>Last Name: {this.props.lastName}</div>
            <div>Email: {this.props.email}</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;



//SearchBar component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Profile from './Profile';

class SearchBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    fetchUser: {
      username: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      hobby: ''
    }
  }
  this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this);
}


 fetchUser() {
    var id = this.refs.id.value;

    axios.get('http://awesomeserver/users/${id}')
      .then(resp => resp.json()) 
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          fetchUser: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input ref="id" placeholder="Enter in a username" />
          <button onClick={this.fetchUser}>Search</button>
          <Profile firstName={this.fetchUser.firstName} lastName={this.fetchUser.lastName} email={this.fetchUser.email} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you use axios is incorrect here, we need to set the returned value to props correctly, and we also need to bind the axios callback function properly, for example, your code should look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>First Name: {this.props.firstName}</div>
            <div>Last Name: {this.props.lastName}</div>
            <div>Email: {this.props.email}</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;



//SearchBar component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Profile from './Profile';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fetchUser: {
        username: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        hobby: ''
      }
    }
    this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this);
  }

  fetchUser() {
    axios.get('http://awesomeserver/users.username')
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log("response", response);
        this.setState({
          fetchUser: response.data
        });
        console.log("fetchUser", this.state.fetchUser);
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input placeholder="Enter in a username" />
          <button onClick={this.fetchUser}>Search</button>
          <Profile firstName={this.state.fetchUser.firstName} lastName={this.state.fetchUser.lastName} email={this.state.fetchUser.email} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Please also check the `response` in the console, to make sure you have got the correct object. Please post here some errors from the console if any, thanks!

Comment: I tried your solution and the `response` is an object and the data property is the array of objects. That is working, but I have an error message of 404 when I tried to do the search. This only happens when I tried to search for names like John Smith, Jane Doe, etc. Also, I was not able to retrieve the correct data like first name and last name. Is it because `response` is not the array of object? How would I retrieve only the username's data that correspond to the search bar?

Comment: I have just changed the axios callback a bit, please try again! It seems that the first ".then()" will return http reaponse object, then we should convert it into json first. However, did you see anything on the console, response object or other errors?

Comment: If the response is an object with data key, then use "response.data" plz. About your search returning 404, which means your api could not be found, or maybe you can upgrade your api, if users try to search some names that don't exist, you should return dummy data, or return "has_data: false" (added to json result)

Comment: I just realized that the object has id and that I should be searching by id and not by name. I did not get anymore `404` error. I apologize for confusing you. As for the response object, I did however got a different error. This is the error: `TypeError: resp.json is not a function`. I even tried to change it to `resp.data.json()` and got the same error except it is `resp.data.json is not a function`. Do you know what is causing it? Also, I updated my code in the original post to match all the changes that had been made.

Comment: OK then, if the API returns fine now, so please change back to my previous version, but with binding the "response.data" to our "fetchUser" (please see my modified answer above). If it still doesn't work yet, feel free to show me what "response" and "this.state.fetchUser" truly return (that I used console.log to capture them)

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Have you made this work yet? If not yet, I may change code to use fetch or something like that to make it work in your case!

Comment: Oh really, glad you made it. If there's no more errors, then could you please consider an upvote as well as accept my answer, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fetchUsers` function on click of search button, so instead of returning the response set the data in State variable by using `setState`, when you do `setState` react will re-render the component and it will pass the profile data to Profile component.

Write the **SearchBar** component like this:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {

  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
          profileDetails: {}
      }
      this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this);
  }

  fetchUser() {
      axios.get('http://awesomeserver/users.username')
      .then((response) => {
          this.setState({profileDetails: response.data})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
             <input placeholder="Enter in a username" />
             <button onClick={this.fetchUser}>Search</button>
             <Profile {...this.state.profileDetails} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Check the [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for details about **{...}**.

Comment: facing any issue in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an axios request like that. Axios result is async and it won't return you the result from the function, so `this.fetchUsers.firstName` etc is meaningless. Call the function and save the result in state in the axios callback like

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: ''
  }
  fetchUser = () => {
      axios.get('http://awesomeserver/users.username')
            .then(res => {
                 return res.json()
            }).then(response => {
                  this.setState({firstName: response.firstName, lastName: response.lastName, email: response.email})
             })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input placeholder="Enter in a username" />
          <button onClick={this.fetchUser}>Search</button>
          <Profile firstName={this.state.firstName} lastName={this.state.lastName} email={this.state.email} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```